# Console Background Music

Tags: c#, console, background-music

I have a `C#` Console game I'm working on and I'd really like to incorporate some background music into it.

I have a function that calls the SoundPlayer and I have it playing music as anticipated.  My function will be called upon certain circumstances of my game, but when it is called I would like for the game to continue. Currently, my game loops through as expected, but once it hits the `playMusic()` function the game comes to a standstill until the music stops playing.

How do I make the music play in the background without interrupting  my main game loop?  Any thoughts on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

The music function:

```
public void playMusic()
    { 
        SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
        sndPlayer.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Music.Wav";           
        sndPlayer.PlaySync();

    }
```

My Game Loop:

```
        int gameoverCount =0;
        //Main game loop
        while (gameoverCount != 1000)
        {
            //Select a random NPC to move
            int randomNPC = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(0, npcs.characters.Count);

            //Checks if the NPC has reached it's destination, if not move. 
            if (npcs.characters[randomNPC].destination)
            {
                Movement.npcMove(board, npcs.characters[randomNPC]);
            }                
            else
            {
                //Gives NPC new location
                npcs.characters[randomNPC].destinationX = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(3, 14);
                npcs.characters[randomNPC].destinationY = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(3, 14);
                npcs.characters[randomNPC].destination = true;
            }
            gameoverCount++;
            Movement.playerMove(p1.coordX, p1.coordY, board, p1, p1.bac, p1.stepsTaken, npcs.characters[randomNPC]);

            //If player is on a certain space, play music
            if (board.board[p1.coordX, p1.coordY].playMusic)
            {
                playMusic();
            }                
            Console.Clear();
            board.showBoard();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Play](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) or the [PlayLooping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playlooping(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) method. As you can see in the remarks section, both these methods will play the music using a new thread. [PlaySync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2), on the other hand, uses the current thread, which is the reason why you get the behavior you're getting.

Comment: Thank you so much, I greatly appreciate your help!